# Can I move from a login View to a SplitView in an iPad application?

Tags: ipad, view, uisplitviewcontroller, loginview

Hope there is not an answer yet (I've checked). Can I introduce a login View in my application that enables a SplitView by using a button or something?
I've checked MGSplitViewController, but I'd like to use something more light and minimal.
If it's not possible, can I introduce a login View in my DetaiView that enables a TableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transition between arbitrary view controllers in iOS.  The usual ways are using modal presentation (I like to present splash screens with a cross-dissolve animation to the root view controller of the app), or pushing/popping with navigation controllers.   You can also programatically swap between multiple views in a view controller via setting the "view" property.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually solved my problem by present login view modally, and by using fullScreen as presentationStyle generic user doesn't mind about the fact it's a modal view!